# Adding get() to line causes "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the start of an inventory system I am working on. Basically it takes an array with items and quantities in a compressed form and outputs the items into an item div.

Running the below produces no error:

```
$('.item_amount').html(collection[itemName].amo);
```

Adding the get() method after the selector like so:

```
$('.item_amount').get(i).html(collection[itemName].amo);
```

produces "$(".item_amount").get(i).html is not a function".

This is what the line is altering:

```
        <div class="item">
        <img src="" class="item_image"/>
        <div class="item_amount"></div>
    </div>
```

The line that is causing the error is located in a for loop that loops through all the keys in an array. Then outputs the item quantity from the array in the item_amount div based on the index stored in the variable "i". The for loop also creates an object for each item in the array and puts in the a collection object.

Full code below:

```
    <body>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="" class="item_image"/>
        <div class="item_amount"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="" class="item_image"/>
        <div class="item_amount"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="" class="item_image"/>
        <div class="item_amount"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var collection = new Object(); 

    function makeItem(itemName, id, amo) {
        collection[itemName] = new item(id, amo); 
    }

    function item(id, amo) { 
        this.id = id;
        this.amo = amo;

    }


    var inventoryCom = "368.9,366.15,384.32"; //compressed inventory
    var inventoryArr = inventoryCom.split(','); 

    for(var i=0; i < inventoryArr.length; i++) {

        var itemName = 'item' + (i + 1); //unique name for each item
        var itemArr = inventoryArr[i].split('.'); 

        makeItem(itemName, itemArr[0], itemArr[1]); 


        $('.item_amount').get(i).html(collection[itemName].amo);
           }

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.get(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns DOM element, which doesn't have `.html()` method - that's what js engine wants to say to you.

You need to use [`.eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead. Like

```
$('.item_amount').eq(i).html(collection[itemName].amo);
```

or

```
$('.item_amount:eq(' + i + ')').html(collection[itemName].amo);
```

Comment: This worked. I think I have a similar problem with: $('.item_image').get(i).attr('src', collection[itemName].img); What should I use instead of get()?

Comment: @Nick: you won't believe, but you should use `.eq()`. No offence, but why don't you read documentation and program by using random functions?

Comment: ah. sorry. thanks for helping. sometimes it's easier to ask than research, since the documentation can be difficult to understand sometimes for newbies.

Comment: @Nick: at least you should try it first ;-) "sometimes it's easier to ask than research" is not a good justification here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This line may be a problem

```
 var itemName = 'item' + (i + 1); //
```

This may increment the array count out of the upper bound. check the itemName value.

Also try to add an alert for this

```
 collection[itemName].amo
```

Comment: you need to put the output of the listitem in the div right?  If so we dont need the 'code' $('.item_amount').get(i).html(collection[itemName].amo);   Instead you need to use 'code' $('.item_amount').html(collection[itemName].amo);